# Disable multi touch createjs

Tags: createjs

I need to have touch support but not multi-touch. 
when I add this: createjs.Touch.enable(_stage);
this will work well on mobile: myMC.on("pressmove", _mouseM);

but i've read that it also enables multi touch. how can I add a press move functionality without using this: createjs.Touch.enable(_stage);

my on("click",_mouseC); events works well if i don't add: createjs.Touch.enable(_stage);

any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter for the `enable` function is `singleTouch` set by default to false, so if you do `createjs.Touch.enable(_stage, true)` it will do what you want.